# What are the consequences of not having an .htaccess file?

Tags: migrations

If I have an .htaccess file installed then I get HTTP 500 errors but if I rename it then I can get farther into the site - although not down to the nodes.

I'm unsure whether to pursue the problem with the .htaccess file there, or not.  System works locally, I am trying to install it on my ISP.

Comment: whats your server config? is it different in local and remote ?

Comment: I ended up installing the .htaccess file on the server and going with that.  The biggest problem I had was that the modules and themes that worked OK in the profiles directory locally, would not work remotely.  When I copied all the modules and themes across to the sites directory then things all worked.  I still don't understand why it worked locally and not remote and I'm not familair with profiles directory.  I ended up getting there but it was a struggle!  I will check that the remote changes work when local.